# Create a smart environment

Tags: smart-home

I'm doing a pet project these days. Plan is to control room environment using an android application.  So far I was able to found Sensibo to control AC and Philips hue bulb to change room light. Both devices have open source api or a Sdk. Next I want a essential oil diffuser which has api or sdk. 
Please submit your ideas or alternatives. Thanks

Comment: Why does a oil diffuser need to be smart? A normal mains powered one plugged into a smart socket will solve this problem

Comment: This question is really too open ended to have a clear answer, so it is not a good fit for the SE network.

Comment: @hardillb there are oil diffusers that can control from vendors mobile application or using google Alexa. I'm looking for a one with open API, SDK to manage all this from a single Android app. all those things should be handled based on events and conditions defined on the mobile app.